# Weird NLog behavior across threads with MDLC and NDLC

Tags: c#, multithreading, nlog

I'm trying to setup a CorrelationID across threads to establish a link between calls to my server, and the corresponding calls that I make to external web services. The correlation ID is a GUID which I'm saving in Logical Context structures of NLog (logical contexts work fine across threads, supposedly).

The idea is to have a GUID that is shared between any request to my server, and the corresponding requests that I issue to various web services due to this request. I tried using both MDLC and NDLC.

The problem is that the value is getting stored correctly only for the first request, and it's saving blank values for all subsequent ones, even though a GUID is correctly generated for each new request to my server.

I tried logging either to a database or in a file. The problem seems to solve itself if I add a breakpoint within the code, or if I add a System.Threading.Sleep anywhere around the logging method. What's also weird is that I can add the Sleep either before or after the method that sets the value in the logical context, and it still works either way. Removing the Sleep/breakpoint would cause it to break again.

I am using NLog v4.5.2.

Logging module:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;
using NLog;

namespace Shift.Stardust.Engine.Modules
{
    public class LoggingHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += HandleBeginRequest;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        private void HandleBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Push(guid);
        }
    }
}
```

Placing a breakpoint anywhere in HandleBeginRequest produces correct output. Similarly for adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500). Naturally, I wouldn't want to add such a line in my code just to resolve this issue.

NLog config:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/logs"/>
  <targets>
    <target name="asyncdatabase"
            xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
            queueLimit="5000"
            overflowAction="Block">
        <target xsi:type="Database"
                connectionStringName="ConnectionStringHere"
                keepConnection="true">
            <commandText>[db].[P_Log_Insert] @CreateDate, @ApplicationName, @MachineName, @LoggerName, @LogLevel, @Message, @Exception, NULL, @EngineSessionId, @CorrelationId</commandText>
            <parameter name="@CreateDate" layout="${date}"/>
            <parameter name="@ApplicationName" layout="${appsetting:name=Shift.Stardust.ApplicationName}"/>
            <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}"/>
            <parameter name="@LoggerName" layout="${logger}"/>
            <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
            <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>
            <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}"/>
            <parameter name="@EngineSessionId" layout="${aspnet-sessionid}"/>
            <parameter name="@CorrelationId" layout="${ndlc}"/>
        </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Http.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="asyncdatabase" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I expect to have a different CorrelationID for each incoming request, but this is only true for the first one. All of the subsequent ones have an empty string as value.

Comment: In the [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogEvent-Context-Information#nesteddiagnosticslogicalcontext), it is used like:  `using (NLog.NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Push("My Scope"))
{
   logger.Info("myLogEvent");
}` ... is that a hint? I never used it myself.

Comment: @Fildor this works if you want scoped logging, which isn't the case for me unfortunately.

Comment: Have you considered using `${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}` from NLog.Web. Requires  "IIS ETW feature". See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetTraceIdentifier-Layout-Renderer and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpTracing/ + http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2012/02/07/code-request-correlation-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to write to the HTTP context for this case.

e.g.

```cs
HttpContext.Current.Items["myvariable"] = 123;
```

and usage:

```
${aspnet-item:variable=myvariable} - produces "123"
```

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetItem-layout-renderer)

You need the package [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web) (ASP.NET non-core) for that.

Note: ASP.NET Core uses should use [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore) instead of NLog.Web

Comment: Thanks, this actually works, but honestly I'm still frustrated because I don't understand this weird behavior (breakpoint = problem solved, no breakpoint = empty values)...